# Send Email through Firebase with file attachment using SendGrid

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage, sendgrid

I have created an application using Flutter. This application creates a text file this is uploaded to firebase storage. I have write a function where an Email could be send through Firebase using SendGrid, as it shows below.
I'm trying to access Storage in firebase through Firebase functions to attach a text file and send it using SendGrid.
The code below is only to send a message using firebase function.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as sgMail from '@sendgrid/mail';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();


const API_KEY = '************************************************************';
const TEMPLATE_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
sgMail.setApiKey(API_KEY);


export const sendFile = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {


  // I'm supposed to access Storage and attached the file into SendGrid to be sent to the following address
  const msg = {
    to:'xxx@gmail.com',
    from:'xxx@outlook.com',
    templateId: TEMPLATE_ID,
    dynamic_template_data: {
      subject: data.subject,
      name: data.name,
    },
  };
  
  try{
    await sgMail.send(msg); 
  }catch (e){
    console.log('Error snedGrid attachment: '+e);
    return {error: e};
  }

  
  return {success: true};
});
```

Comment: You can [download](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-nodejs) file into function's [/tmp](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system) directory and then attach it to email.

Comment: @NibrassH I notice several of your recent approved edits have an edit summary of "Improve Grammar" where in fact your changes are completely unrelated to grammar fixes. Is this just an oversight, or perhaps something far more sinister? Either way, please take care to actually summarize your changes in the change summary.